# Twitter Ads API in R

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, endpoint

I have the following:

`App Name
 API_Key
 API_Secret
 Access_Token
 Access_Secret
 Account ID`

I want to simply get the performance metrics by day for all campaigns under 1 account ID in Twitter Ads.

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)
library(parsedate)
library(BBmisc)
library(httr)

appname <- “xxxxx”
api_key <- “xxxxxxx”
api_secret <- “xxxxxxxx”
access_token <- “xxxxxxx”
access_secret <- “xxxxxx”
account_id <- “xxxxxxx”

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret, access_token, access_secret)

reach_campaign.request <- 
GET(“https://ads-api.twitter.com/1/stats/accounts/xxxxxxx/reach/campaigns?start_time=2018-06-10T00:00:00+01:00Z&campaign_ids=xxxxx&end_time=2018-06-15T00:00:00+01:00Z 7”,
query = list(granularity = “DAY”,
metric_groups = “ENGAGEMENT”,
placement = “ALL_ON_TWITTER”),
accept_json(),
config(token = access_secret))
```

Does anyone know how to simply just get the results by Day for the Account ID as a whole?

This was my attempt but I got a 403 error:

```
path <- paste("https://ads-api.twitter.com/1/stats/accounts/", account_id, sep="")
getinfo <- GET(path)
newContent <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getinfo)))
```

Comment: API version has been deprecated for some time. Could you try using version 4 : `https://ads-api.twitter.com/4/stats/accounts/` [as documented](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/analytics/api-reference/synchronous#resource-url)

Comment: Thanks, I'm away from my computer right now but will try this out tomorrow